# Server managment studio Export/Import Tables: The Ordering of Execution in SSIS Package

Tags: sql-server, ssis

im making some SSIS package to import data from production servers to my own local databases.

The question is, is there a way to order the execution of the tables?

Problem:
Table1: PK Table2Key FK Table1Key
Table2: PK Table2Key

It seams the ordering gets chosen based on the names of the tables. 
So here it will try Table1 first, this will fail couse there are forign key constraints to Table2

I want Table2 to get fetched before Table1. 
I tried editing the order of the components in the ssis package, this did not work :(

Kind regards Tor Einar

Answer (score 0):

Using the Import/Export wizard, there is no way to order the events short of creating/executing a package to handle Table2 first and then go back through the wizard to handle Table1. The default when you select multiple tables in this wizard is that a single data flow is built out and the actions are all performed in parallel.

You would need the full installation of BIDS/SSDT-BI to design a package with precedence constraints.

Comment: Thank you, i ended up making several scripts for execution intervals that fits the forign key constraints :)